# Reading json file as string spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, unit-testing, jackson

```
ServiceApplicationTest{
  public static final String CONNECTED_CALL="{\"Sid\":\"835494\",\"Info\":\"121345\"}
}
```

Strings like "CONNECTED_CALL" can be very long, this is not preety but is working fine.
My goal is to move all this kind of data to file in resource folder like - connectedCall.json and read it without making any major change.

I dont want to change already written code, I am fine with adding complexity to populate this values.

One way I had is to read these json file as string, calling this function for every value but then they cant be final.

Can i do it using any annotation? like @Value in spring boot.
I am using jackson.

Comment: Reading json file but they can't be final? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Enfieldli- final strings have to declared and initialised together.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `@PropertySource` something like :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:json.properties")
public class JsonConfig {
       
       @Value("${CONNECTED_CALL}")
       String jsonVal;
}
```

And your json.properties file will have :

```
CONNECTED_CALL="{\"Sid\":\"835494\",\"Info\":\"121345\"}
```

This can be one of the way.

Comment: This will pollute my properties file. Only properties  file related on the basis of deployment are allowed.

Comment: Then another option which I can think of is  to use db or file storage & refer it in your application either via repository interface or via any db drivers.